# mongodb speed on remote server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongomapper

I have my vps on linode but I found It is  32 bits and when I installed mongodb ,It installed the 32 bits version of mongodb which is limited to 2GB memory ..Mongodb is interesting really and It fits my need on my rails 3 application ,I can't change my Ubuntu version to install 64 bits  of mongodb ..what about installing mongodb on another vps ...how can I connect it with my rails application using mongomapper gem also does these method affect the speed of mongodb connection with my rails application ?

Comment: And will it affect the connection -- of course -- it's connecting to another VPS. How much will require testing in the environment you're considering using.

Comment: I need to install 64 version of mongodb on my vps but I dont want to re-install the OS from scratch again ..do you have any solutions for that?

Comment: You installed a 32 bit OS and now you want 64 bit? You'll need to reinstall.